# API about communication between RoR and Git server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git

My RoR app needs to checkout the file from local git server and display its content.

Dose any API or module support the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [ruby-git](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git) and [grit](https://github.com/schacon/grit).